# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven, spring-mvc

I use this [tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-jdbctemplate-example) for Spring MVC example, but I use PostgreSQL.

And I have a lot of exceptions, I have searched but nothing helped.

This is Exception:

```
    SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO net.codejava.spring.controller.HomeController.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getContactDAO' defined in class path resource [net/codejava/spring/config/MvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO net.codejava.spring.config.MvcConfiguration.getContactDAO()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [net/codejava/spring/config/MvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource net.codejava.spring.config.MvcConfiguration.getDataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]
```

If I understand right I have a problem with load JDBC Driver, but I already added this in pom.xml

My source code:

**MvcConfiguration**:

```
package net.codejava.spring.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAOImpl;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="net.codejava.spring")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/contactdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("3517571");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ContactDAO getContactDAO() {
        return new ContactDAOImpl(getDataSource());
    }
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
package net.codejava.spring.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.model.Contact;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * This controller routes accesses to the application to the appropriate
 * hanlder methods. 
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
        List<Contact> listContact = contactDAO.list();
        model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
        model.setViewName("home");

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        model.addObject("contact", newContact);
        model.setViewName("ContactForm");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
        contactDAO.saveOrUpdate(contact);       
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        contactDAO.delete(contactId);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Contact contact = contactDAO.get(contactId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
        model.addObject("contact", contact);

        return model;
    }
}
```

**ContactDAO:**

```
package net.codejava.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import net.codejava.spring.model.Contact;

/**
 * Defines DAO operations for the contact model.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public interface ContactDAO {

    public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact);

    public void delete(int contactId);

    public Contact get(int contactId);

    public List<Contact> list();
}
```

**ContactDAOImpl:**

```
package net.codejava.spring.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import net.codejava.spring.model.Contact;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

/**
 * An implementation of the ContactDAO interface.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */

public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public ContactDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact) {
        if (contact.getId() > 0) {
            // update
            String sql = "UPDATE contact SET name=?, email=?, address=?, "
                        + "telephone=? WHERE contact_id=?";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                    contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone(), contact.getId());
        } else {
            // insert
            String sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, address, telephone)"
                        + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                    contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int contactId) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM contact WHERE contact_id=?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contactId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Contact> list() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM contact";
        List<Contact> listContact = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Contact>() {

            @Override
            public Contact mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Contact aContact = new Contact();

                aContact.setId(rs.getInt("contact_id"));
                aContact.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                aContact.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                aContact.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                aContact.setTelephone(rs.getString("telephone"));

                return aContact;
            }

        });

        return listContact;
    }

    @Override
    public Contact get(int contactId) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE contact_id=" + contactId;
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<Contact>() {

            @Override
            public Contact extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                    DataAccessException {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setId(rs.getInt("contact_id"));
                    contact.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                    contact.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                    contact.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                    contact.setTelephone(rs.getString("telephone"));
                    return contact;
                }

                return null;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.codejava.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMvcJdbcTemplate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SpringMvcJdbcTemplate</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Servlet Spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>      
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMvcJdbcTemplate</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This is on the bottom of your stack trace: "Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]". Is your JDBC driver on the classpath?

Comment: I added my pom.xml, check please

Comment: i have dependency from 9.3-1102-jdbc41 and spring-jdbc 4.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: Hard to diagnose with no direct to the code and your IDE. The symptoms are consistent with the driver not being available on the classpath, you can try to verify if it's there or not using this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16747607/1240557

Comment: Are you mean this?
http://s011.radikal.ru/i317/1512/08/527f3b2f93b7.png

Comment: hmm... really my other project could found this driver but this project was not able to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your project, to download all libraries and then you will see the absolute path for postgresql Driver.

Comment: This is maven project, so you need to download all dependencies (all jars).. You can update your maven repository by right click on the project > Maven > Update project..
I assume that you are using eclipse or STS

Comment: but i use IDEA, can i do that in IDEA?

Comment: i can do it! Right click on project -> maven -> Reimport

Comment: I dont understand why its happened?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the same error in intellij idea by switching from jdk-16 to jdk-13 in my pom.xml and in my project sdk (File --> project structure --> project --> jdk-13).
Further more i was using servlet api instead of web.xml