# Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I am a beginner to Spring

I was trying to test my connection to database(postgresql) and thus wrote following simple piece of code. But it is throwing this error which i am not able to resolve.

**Error thrown**:

```
Jul 05, 2017 12:01:13 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4534b60d: startup date [Wed Jul 05 12:01:13 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 05, 2017 12:01:14 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Jul 05, 2017 12:01:14 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ds' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.javatpoint.Test.main(Test.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510)
    ... 13 more

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ds' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.javatpoint.Test.main(Test.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510)
    ... 13 more
```

My main class is **Employee.java** :

```
package com.javatpoint;

public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float salary;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int id, String name, float salary) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

My Dao file is **EmployeeDao.java** :

```
package com.javatpoint;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class EmployeeDao {
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public int saveEmployee(Employee e){
    String query="insert into employee values('"+e.getId()+"','"+e.getName()+"','"+e.getSalary()+"')";
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query);
}
public int updateEmployee(Employee e){
    String query="update employee set name='"+e.getName()+"',salary='"+e.getSalary()+"' where id='"+e.getId()+"' ";
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query);
}
public int deleteEmployee(Employee e){
    String query="delete from employee where id='"+e.getId()+"' ";
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query);
}

}
```

My xml file is **applicationContext.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />    
<property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Testing" />
<property name="username" value="postgres" />
<property name="password" value="hlinaknk" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="edao" class="com.javatpoint.EmployeeDao">
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

And my test file is **Test.java** :

```
package com.javatpoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)ctx.getBean("edao");

        try {
              Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
              //on classpath
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
              // not on classpath
            }

        int status=dao.saveEmployee(new Employee(102,"Amit",35000));
        System.out.println(status);

        /*int status=dao.updateEmployee(new Employee(102,"Sonoo",15000));
        System.out.println(status);
        */

        /*Employee e=new Employee();
        e.setId(102);
        int status=dao.deleteEmployee(e);
        System.out.println(status);*/

    }

}
```

**Can anyone please suggest what is going on wrong here?**

Comment: Looks like you have to add the jar which contains the driverclass to your classpath

Comment: `org.postgresql.Driver` is not in classpath.

Comment: There are tons of handy links around to solve this problem https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-postgresql/

Comment: @ Jens & Jay : I had included spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar already

Comment: Having spring-jdbc on your classpath does not magically add the PostgreSQL JDBC driver to your classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error popping up:

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]
```

Test if "org.postgresql.Driver" is on your classpath like so:

```
try {
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  //on classpath
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
  //not on classpath
}
```

You might wanna read this question: [getting error: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743544/getting-error-could-not-load-jdbc-driver-class-org-postgresql-driver)

Comment: I saw that link and also added suggested try and catch block in my Test.java  
Still it gives same error

Comment: so inside the try block, its executing post the Class.forName? its not going into the catch block?

Comment: @user6038386 But you have to include that code snippet BEFORE the spring initialization in `ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");`

Comment: Yes finally it works now

I had to download postgresql jdbc driver and add it in my classpath

Thanks to all!!

Comment: @ RubioRic : you are right, I did that edit in my code

Answer (score 0):

I had this error while trying to run a war file in tomcat 7 despite adding a postgresql dependency in my maven project. I resolved it by updated to tomcat 8 and then downloading this file: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.5.jar and putting it in the `lib` folder of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Oracle's JDBC connector to `Tomcat/lib/` worked for me.

You can get it from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc.html, hope it helps.